# Is await not allowed in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Can anyone explain why I am getting

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

from the below, as I am using `await` inside an `async` function?

```
(async function(){
  'use strict';

  const express = require("express");
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const app = express();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    await console.log('a');
    res.status(200).end();
  });

  app.listen(config.webhook_port, () => console.log("Listening"));
})();
```

The above is a simplified version of a webhook listener, which could get many webhooks at the same time. So the use of `console.log()` in the code is just to simulate a function that would get called. So inside the `app.post()` will there be logic to decide on what do do with each received webhook.

The reason I want to use `await` is so I can check the return value of the function.

Comment: `async (req, res) => {`?

Comment: express is a javascript library. It can't change language syntax. It's simply not possible. You are using `await` in a local arrow function, which isn't async.

Comment: The function you pass to app.post is a callback which means it will be called at a later time. And this function is not async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the outer async, then write:

```
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    await console.log('a');
    res.status(200).end();
  });
```